# Using sqlite3 in an Angular + Electron app: Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Tags: angular, sqlite, webpack, electron, node-sqlite3

In my [Angular + Electron app](https://github.com/azerothcore/Keira3) I'm trying to install some sqlite library in order to read contents from an sqlite database file.

I've installed [sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3) using:

```
npm install sqlite3
npm install --save-dev @types/sqlite3
```

And I've tried to use it doing:

```
import * as sqlite from 'sqlite3';

// ...

const myDb = new sqlite.Database('/path/to/file.sqlite');
```

However when the application builds it fails with:

> WARNING in ./node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js 4:14-35 Critical
>   dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js 20:22-48
>   Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/versioning.js 17:20-67
>   Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> WARNING in ../node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js 124:16-56 Critical
>   dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> WARNING in ../node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js 235:10-25 Critical
>   dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> WARNING in
>   ../node_modules/npm/node_modules/encoding/lib/iconv-loader.js 9:12-34
>   Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'node-gyp' in
>   '/home/shin/sources/Keira3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util'
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html
>   1:0 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0) You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are
>   configured to process this file. See
>   https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
>
> > |  |
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/info.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' in
>   '/home/shin/sources/Keira3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/publish.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' in
>   '/home/shin/sources/Keira3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/unpublish.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' in
>   '/home/shin/sources/Keira3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib' ERROR in
>   ../node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js 1:0 Module parse failed: Unexpected
>   character '#' (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this
>   file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.
>   See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
>
> > ## !/usr/bin/env node | ;(function () { // wrapper in case we're in module_context mode |   // windows: running "npm blah" in this folder
> >
> > will invoke WSH, not node.

In [this thread](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/1029) a solution to this issue is posted and it's about adding the following to the webpack config file:

```
externals: { 'sqlite3':'commonjs sqlite3', }
```

however it is not clear to me where to add such config in my Angular app.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my issue using [Custom webpack builders (angular-builders)](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack).

> Allow customizing build configuration without ejecting webpack configuration (ng eject)

After installing it, I'm now able to specify a custom webpack config where I've added:

```
module.exports = {
    externals: {
        'sqlite3':'commonjs sqlite3'
    }
};
```

I also had to run `node postinstall && electron-builder install-app-dep` in order to make it work.